# Using textbox value for a class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

i'm trying to use my Textbox value from another form to a class to insert items to my database. 
I tried creating another instance of my Form1 which is the name of the form I want to get the value from but it returns 0 items to my database when I click my submit button is there anyway to do this?

```
public void Insert()
    {
        Form1 mform = new Form1();
        string query = "INSERT INTO parts (item_id, description, brand, model, color, quantity) VALUES('0', '"
               + mform.Description.Text
                 + "','" + mform.Brand.Text
                + "','" + mform.Model.Text
                + "','" + mform.Color.Text
                + "','" + mform.Quantity.Text + "')";

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);            
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
           this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did  you debug your code and see what your insert command looks like exactly? Is it working in your database manager? What `OpenConnection` and `CloseConnection` do? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: hmm i only need it for my midterm exam so i have no worries about any attacks

Comment: As Soner says, you should never do what you're doing, adding up strings to make a SQL command. Another mistake is to create a new Form with the "new" keyword, then trying to access values from it. It's brand new, you just made it, The Brand, Model and Color are all empty.
The flow needs to be "New Form" -> "User types into TextBoxes" -> "User Clicks Button and you insert into database"

Comment: For that you need to pass the instance object of that form to the insert function and have to make the textbox object available by changing access specifier to internal not recomended.

Comment: @MikeyMouse ok sir thank you for the suggestion i'll try using user types i totally forgot that i can use those since i've been focusing on my minor subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a new instance of the `Form1()` object, you are assuming that the new instance's "Description, Brand, Model, Color and Quantity" `TextBox's` contains text? The default value of a `TextBox.Text` is the default value of its `string` property type, `null`.

Ideally, you will take the values that the user has populated from the form instance and then pass them into the DB like so:

```
public void Insert()
{
    using (var mform = new Form1())
    {
        // Ensure that the user entered values...
        if (mform.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO parts (item_id, description, brand, model, color, quantity) VALUES('0', '"
               + mform.Description.Text
               + "','" + mform.Brand.Text
               + "','" + mform.Model.Text
               + "','" + mform.Color.Text
               + "','" + mform.Quantity.Text + "')";

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
               var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you should avoid inline SQL and instead use stored procedures, or at the very least use `SqlParameter's`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access `Form1` values in a `class` by creating new instance. To access `textbox` values you need to do the following:

1. Create public `property` in a `class`
2. Assign property with `textbox` value in some appropriate event (such as `TextChanged`)
3. Access property inside class to get `textbox` value and save it to database.

**Example**

*Class:*

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public string IncomingValue { get; set; }

    public string SaveToDatabase()
    {
        string valueToSave = IncomingValue;

        // Insert into database

        return "Success";
    }
}
```

*Form:*

```
DataAccess access = new DataAccess();

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    access.IncomingValue = textBox1.Text;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(access.SaveToDatabase());
}
```

Also, I would suggest you to use [Parametrized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx). This will give you more readability and saves you from SQL injection and confusion.